# How can I save and restore TTY settings from a subshell? (Or: understanding pty/tty within subshells)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, tty, pty

I am trying to understand `stty`'s operation within a subshell.  Here is a small Ruby script I am working with to wrap my head around the behavior.  I'm just trying to save and restore the `tty` state after we exit an infinite loop via `^C`.

```rb
original_tty = `stty -f /dev/tty -g`
begin
  loop do end
rescue Interrupt
  # Suppress exception
ensure
  $stderr.puts `stty -f /dev/tty #{original_tty}`
  $stderr.puts "stty exits with: #{$?}, i.e. success == #{$?.success?}"
end
```

Now, if you put this into a file `wut.rb`, when I run it at my command line with `bash -c 'echo | ruby wut.rb` it works; *i.e.* `stty` returns `0`.  But if I run it in a subshell *via* command substitution, `bash -c 'echo $(echo | ruby wut.rb)'`, it does not; *i.e.* `stty` returns `1`.

Running these directly from the command line works as I might expect:

```
$ foo=$(stty -f /dev/tty -g)
$ echo $foo
gfmt1:cflag=4b00:iflag=6b02:lflag=200005cf:oflag=3:discard=f:dsusp=19:eof=4:eol=ff:eol2=ff:erase=7f:intr=3:kill=15:lnext=16:min=1:quit=1c:reprint=12:start=11:status=14:stop=13:susp=1a:time=0:werase=17:ispeed=38400:ospeed=38400
$ echo | stty -f /dev/tty $foo
$ echo $?
0
$ echo $(echo | stty -f /dev/tty $foo)

$ echo $?
0
```

I'm on Mac OS X 10.10.2 using `bash 3.2` and `ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]` if it matters…

---

Why is this?  I think it has to do with the subshell created by command substitution not being/having a `tty`, but I'm not sure. I would very much appreciate:

- any explanation of what's going on (including good readings on PTY/TTY—so far ["A Brief Introduction to Termios"](https://blog.nelhage.com/2009/12/a-brief-introduction-to-termios/) and ["The TTY demystified"](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) have been the most helpful)
- and suggestions as to how I might successfully restore the original `tty` settings within a command substitution.

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you on? OS X? On Linux with coreutils the corresponding `stty` flag is `-F`, and `stty -F /dev/tty`, `echo | stty -F /dev/tty`, `echo $(echo | stty -F /dev/tty)`, and the same variants via `bash -c` all work as expected (prints tty settings to stdout and returns 0). Whether or not stdin is bound to the tty (which it won't be when you pipe the output of `echo` to it, of course) shouldn't matter when you specify the tty explicitly. Try running `stty` directly instead of via your Ruby script, though I'd be surprised if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Ulfalizer Yeah, I'm on OS X; updated post to include that info. The flag is -f—so on your system, when you run this script, does it work as you expect? Running those directly from the CLI works as expected; updated the question to include the terminal transcript.

Comment: stty should print error messages to stderr. If you don't see any error message *and* the return code is non-zero, you are probably not running what you think you are running.

Comment: I can duplicate the problem by doing `bash -c 'echo $(ruby test.rb)'` (whether stdin is from `echo` makes no difference here), which gives *stty: /dev/tty: Input/output error*. `zsh -c` gives the same result, but curiously `dash -c` works. Not sure what's going on, but it's probably related to how the shells deal with the `SIGINT` generated by Ctrl-C, and maybe has to do with backgrounded process groups.

Comment: @Ulfalizer Hm— I wonder whether the `dash` _v._ `bash` difference has to do with [this on SIGNIT handling](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=683671)?  Thanks for tracking that difference down!

Comment: @n.m. Not sure what you mean by "not running what you think you are running"—Could you clarify?

Comment: Not the right stty executable?

Comment: @n.m. I think it's right— I get `/bin/stty` in my shell and subshell when I run it within `wut.rb`, _e.g._ _via_ [this, modified `wut.rb`](https://gist.github.com/aresnick/6ac0f70ded87f5c21a9e).

Comment: `stty` (on Linux) does print an error message: `stty: /dev/tty: Input/output error`.

Comment: @aresnick: Could be. Gets into some shell arcana. :)